# UITextField font issue in iOS7 only

Tags: fonts, ios7, uitextfield, xcode5

In my app I have created several textfields using IB, the xib files were originally created with xcode 4 and have now been updated to Xcode 5. The issue I'm having is random textfields throughout the app are displaying text with the wrong font. It seems to make no difference what the font is set to either in IB or programmatically.

Strangely if the view controller is popped and pushed whilst running in simulator the font is sometimes displayed correctly?

I’ve tried setting the font everyway I know, but it makes no difference.  I can only think its an issue with iOS7 in the simulator which won’t appear on an actual iOS7 device. Has anyone else seen this? Thanks.

I have tried deleting and replacing the textField in the xib file. Problem remains.

I have just copied the relevant code to a newly created Xcode 5 project and I'm getting exactly the same issue whether the textField is created in IB or programmatically. All I can think of is there is a bug in the simulator or else there is someway a UITextField can automatically change its font when it's text property is changed? I don't have an actual iOS 7 device to determine whether its a simulator only issue. Someone else must have come across this issue? The same code works fine on iOS 6 and earlier BTW.

I've isolated and stripped back to the basic code causing the issue -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.firstDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
self.firstDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[self.firstDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(firstDateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

self.firstTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(118, 207, 164, 30)];
self.firstTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
self.firstTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Wide" size:14];

self.firstTextField.inputView = self.firstDatePicker;
[self.firstTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(editingBeganFirstDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
[self.view addSubview:self.firstTextField];

self.secondDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
self.secondDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[self.secondDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(secondDateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

self.secondTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(118, 267, 164, 30)];
self.secondTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
self.secondTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Wide" size:14];
self.secondTextField.inputView = self.secondDatePicker;
[self.secondTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(editingBeganSecondDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
[self.view addSubview:self.secondTextField];


}



-(void) editingBeganFirstDate:(UITextField*) sender
{
[self firstDateChanged:self.firstDatePicker];
}

-(void) editingBeganSecondDate:(UITextField*) sender
{
[self secondDateChanged:self.secondDatePicker];
}

-(void) firstDateChanged:(UIDatePicker*) sender
{
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

self.firstTextField.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[sender date]];
}

-(void) secondDateChanged:(UIDatePicker*) sender
{
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

self.secondTextField.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[sender date]];
}
```

It seems the problem arises when calling the action triggered methods "firstDateChanged" & "secondDatechanged" directly in code. I've done this in the "editingBegan" methods and when input focus changes between the textfields the font is changed? I've no idea why this happens but at least I know whats causing it!

Done a bit of reading and found a way to programmatically call an event triggered method. I've changed the "editingBegan" methods to

```
-(void) editingBeganFirstDate:(UITextField*) sender
{
[self.firstDatePicker sendAction:@selector(firstDateChanged:) to:self forEvent:nil];
}

-(void) editingBeganSecondDate:(UITextField*) sender
{
[self.secondDatePicker sendAction:@selector(secondDateChanged:) to:self forEvent:nil];
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't solve the font problem!?

Comment: PLease add your code to your question...

Comment: Anybody have any ideas?? Or have an iOS7 device to check if this is a simulator only issue?

Comment: Did you manage to find the cause?

Comment: Just to let anyone know this is still an issue in Xcode 6 and the iOS8 simulator, but I gather not on any actual devices. This issue would have been more widely reported if present on an actual device.